# Templates for AS3 (like c++)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, class, templates

How do I define C++-like templates in AS3?; I have a map class (2d array) that I want to re-use across projects but the cell data is a different class depending on the project or implementation;

There are a bunch of other reasons regarding sharing code accross different implementations, but I'd hope for somthing like:

```
map = new MyMap<MyCell>();
```

Doesn't matter if it's Flash 10 only :-p

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There aren't templates, but dynamic typing and using classes as values might be good enough for your purposes.

You can make a class that takes a class and stores it as an instance variable.

```
class MyMap {
 var myClass:Class;

 function MyMap(c:Class){
  myClass = c;
 }
}
```

And then you feed the class to it...

```
map = new MyMap(MyCell);
```

And then in methods, you can refer to that class.

```
// Inside MyMap somewhere
var someWhatever:Object = new myClass();
// or
var someWhatever:Object = Object(myClass).someCachingSchemeStaticMethod();
// or whatever.
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't make your own template classes. The only one you have in the whole of AS3 is `Vector`.

There's an open [feature request](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-811) for the same on JIRA. Feel free to upvote.